# Sql Error in android android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token

Tags: android, sqlite, calendar, icalendar

I am querying the android calendars db and looking for an event with particular 'iCalGUID' .

here is the query I am using

```
final Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri.getCalendarUri(),
                        null, "events.iCalGUID=" + uid, null, null);
```

**Current uid is 0804eaa1-3472-43df-96c2-af73ae5c31ab**

But I am getting an exception while executing this query

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "0804eaa1": , 
while compiling: SELECT originalEvent, visibility, rrule, hide_declined, reminder_type, hasAlarm, 
description AS suggest_text_2, rdate, transparency, timezone, dtstart, _sync_time, hasAttendeeData, 
commentsUri, description, reminder_duration, htmlUri, _sync_account, _sync_version, hasExtendedProperties, 
last_update_time, eventLocation, dtend, allDay, organizer, sync_source, deleted, url, originalInstanceTime, alerts_vibrate, importance, selfAttendeeStatus, eventTimezone, ownerAccount, _sync_account_type, lastDate, guestsCanModify, guestsCanSeeGuests, exrule, selected, title, _id, _sync_id, alerts_ringtone, calendar_id, access_level, _sync_local_id, title AS suggest_text_1, originalAllDay, iCalGUID, _sync_dirty, duration, parentID, color, 
guestsCanInviteOthers, 
exdate, eventStatus FROM view_events WHERE (1) 
AND (events.iCalGUID=0804eaa1-3472-43df-96c2-af73ae5c31ab)
```

How could I do this in android 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
final Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri.getCalendarUri(),
                        null, "events.iCalGUID=\"" + uid + "\"", null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. let me ask your help. Now I am getting error column dosen't exists. So I changed events.iCalGUID to view_events.iCalGUID and it works. Is that the right way to query the event column iCalGUID?

Comment: It depends on your table, it should be of the format `yourtablename.yourcolumname=...`

Comment: I am using the default calendar database on android

Comment: I have never used that database I don't know it's structure, so I cant help on this. Maybe this helps: http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151